# Passing HTML attribute to jQuery function from onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, attributes, onclick

I have a problem in passing one of html element to jQuery. I know that with `attr()` we can access to attributes. Nevertheless I feel I do something wrong.

This is my simple jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

I have a dynamic listbox which has been created by foreach loop:

```php
<select  multiple="multiple" name="factors1" id="main_factors" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

<?php foreach ($array as $option): ?>
    <option onclick="test(<script>this.attr('title').value</script>);"
            id="<?php echo $option[0]; ?>"
            title="<?php echo $option[2]; ?>" 
            value="<?php echo $option[0]; ?>">
        <?php echo $option[1]; ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach ?>

</select>
```

I want when somebody click on items in list box its item show in my messagebox for example. However this code did not work for me.

```
onclick="test(<script>this.attr('title').value</script>);"
```

How can I send title attribute value to my function from onclick attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick="test(this)"

function test(value)
{
    alert($(value).attr('title'));
}
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FLMrp/)

Comment: @user108: `onchange` event is better than `onclick` events while using `select` elements

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. I think you make a mistake in your code.

```
<select  multiple="multiple" name="factors1" id="main_factors" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" onchange="test(this.value);">

<?php foreach ($array as $option): ?>
<option id="<?php echo      $option[0]; ?>" title="<?php echo $option[2]; ?>" 
value="<?php  echo $option[0]; ?>"><?php echo $option[1]; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>


</select>
```

And in your jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(value)
       {
        alert(value);
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: `onchange` event is better than `onclick` events while using `select` elements

Comment: `onchange` event should be defined on `<select>` so it will capture value of option when changed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use `onchange` event on `select` element.

```
​<select onchange="test(this.value)">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function test(value) {
    alert(value)        
}​
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/5EPUz/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have imported and are utilizing jQuery, it is better practice to separate your event handlers from your html elements, as a sort of separation of design from functionality:

Remove the `onclick` altogether from your php:

```
<select  multiple="multiple" name="factors1" id="main_factors" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
<?php foreach ($array as $option): ?>
<option id="<?php echo $option[0]; ?>" title="<?php echo $option[2]; ?>" 
value="<?php  echo $option[0]; ?>"><?php echo $option[1]; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

And bind a function to the `change` event from within the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main_factors').change( function() {
        test( $(this).val() );
        // you can also do:
        // test( this.value );
    });
});

function test(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```